# How do I launch an app from my Flutter app programmatically?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I understand there maybe some duplication here, but the other solutions I have found don't do exactly what I need. What I want to do is to launch a particular app and if it isn't installed launch the apps page on Playstore and also AppStore, if using an iPhone. I am pretty close to getting this working, but I need a little help getting over the line.

I have a FloatingAction Button that loads the chosen app and if it isn't installed, loads PlayStore, but it doesn't go directly to the App's page. I haven't testing on iPhone yet, so if that code is garbage, I would appreciate some help there too.

How can I get my app to go straight to the app's page on playstore app and appstore app?

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_appavailability/flutter_appavailability.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('App Availability'),
        ),
        body: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
          onPressed: () => openApp(context),
          child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),
          heroTag: "Open App",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void openApp(BuildContext context) {
  try {
    AppAvailability.launchApp(Platform.isIOS 
      ? "appname://" 
      : "com.company.appname"
    ).then((_) {
      print("App Launched!");
    }).catchError((err) {
      AppAvailability.launchApp(Platform.isIOS 
        ? "appstore://" 
        : "com.android.vending"
      ) 
// I think I will need to add package name to the playstore package name
// in the line above, but not sure how.
// I have tried com.android.vending?id=com.criticalarc.safezoneapp
// and com.android.vending/com.criticalarc.safezoneapp

      .then((_) {});
      print(err);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text("App Not Installed!"),
      ),
    );
    print("App Not Installed!");
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: are you using a try catch to first load iOS store and if that fails andorid play store?

Comment: If the platform is ios, then launch the ios version of the app, otherwise launch the android version. If it is not installed, then launch the relevant app store (Apple, or Google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the the Google Play website link itself

Syntax - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=(complete-with-the-app-package-name)

For eg - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.amahi.anywhere

Comment: I was going to use url_launcher to load the website link as a fallback option, but I would like to use the apps if possible. thanks

Comment: The links worked, as I knew they would, but with this approach, opening the native apps will be reliant on whether the user has set their device to do this if it is installed. For now, it is the accepted answer. Thanks